# Replacement for Moodys BAA and AAA series

Tags: data, spread, bond-yields, indicator

Along with many other people, I have been using Moody's seasoned BAA and AAA corporate bond yield series for my research for some time. I use them primarily to compute and analyze the quality spread.  Unfortunately, it appears that the Fed will [no longer be computing and publishing these series](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BAA).  I've been looking around for a replacement.

The obvious choice, it seemed, was the BofA Merrill Lynch Corporate [BBB yield](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BAMLC0A4CBBBEY) and [AAA yield](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BAMLC0A1CAAAEY) series.  However, plotting the spread between these two against the spread of the old Moody's series, they don't seem to be that close.  Certainly not a continuation nor drop-in replacement.

What's the new consensus data series to be used to look at the quality spread?  Do we just use the BofA Merrill Lynch series or is there another series I'm overlooking?